# why Angular $routeProvider configuration requires an ngView declared in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have no requirement to use `ngView`, but I need to know the route parameters in my controller. So, I tried to inject `$routeParams` in my controller. However it did not work util I declared an `ngView` in my HTML. So, why configuring a `$routeProvider` need an `ngView` (which is actually not needed by my requirement) declared in the HTML?

Code example:
Angular app

```
var routeParamsApp = angular.module('routeParamsApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Configuration file

```
routeParamsApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {controller: 'routeParamsCntrl'}).
    when('/a', {controller: 'routeParamsCntrl'}).
    when('/a/:b', {controller: 'routeParamsCntrl'}).
    when('a/:b/c/d/:e', {controller: 'routeParamsCntrl'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="routeParamsApp" ng-controller="routeParamsCntrl">
    <p>Current $routeParams is: {{routeParams}}</p>
</body>
```

Controller

```
routeParamsApp.controller('routeParamsCntrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.routeParams = $routeParams;
    }]
);
```

Above code does not work until I declare a dummy `<div ng-view></div>` in the HTML. Why? is there any solution to use `$routeParams` inside an controller without declaring an `ngView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive `ng-view` uses as a container to switch between views. I think it tells to AngularJS to do a digest cycle over templates (a.e. compile them as well on beginning).

From [Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView):

> **ngView** is a directive that complements the **$route** service by including the rendered template of the current route into the main layout (index.html) file. Every time the current route changes, the included view changes with it according to the configuration of the $route service.
>
> Requires the **ngRoute** module to be installed.

So we go to `$route`: [Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route):

> ...
>   You can define routes through $routeProvider's API.
>
> The $route service is typically used in conjunction with the **ngView** directive and the **$routeParams** service.

Comment: Thanks for you information! does this mean if I do not put `ngView` in the HTML, in controller I could not listen to `$routeChangeSuccess` event with code `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess'`?

Comment: Right, you can see this demo before and after removing `ng-view`:http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/9MnE9/

Comment: Thank you @Maxim! So, I am not lucky, with this behavior I am not able to use `$routeParams` to extract route parameters and probably I need to manually do that with `$location` service.